# One Drive SDK is giving null pointer exception

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, onedrive

I am using **One Drive application** in my app, when i am calling `IPicker` class from my activity its 
crashing.

I am pasting the error log here, please check it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.microsoft.skydrive/com.microsoft.skydrive.getcontent.RecieveSdkPickerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.microsoft.skydrive.getcontent.RecieveSdkPickerActivity.isAccountSupported(RecieveSdkPickerActivity.java:184)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.microsoft.skydrive.NavigationDrawerPivotsAdapter.setAccounts(NavigationDrawerPivotsAdapter.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.microsoft.skydrive.NavigationDrawerPivotsAdapter.setPivotFilter(NavigationDrawerPivotsAdapter.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.microsoft.skydrive.NavigationDrawerView.setPivotFilter(NavigationDrawerView.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.microsoft.skydrive.itemchooser.BaseOneDriveItemChooserActivity.onCreate(BaseOneDriveItemChooserActivity.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at com.microsoft.skydrive.getcontent.RecieveSdkPickerActivity.onCreate(RecieveSdkPickerActivity.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(13293):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
```

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/OneDrive/OneDrive-Picker-Android lib.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the OneDrive application, if you update to the currently release you shouldn't encounter this issue anymore.